# Far side of the Globe

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So, I have the rotating Globe, and some countries highlights, if you mouseover them.
But the problem is, that countries in far side shouldn't change their color and lands should change their border.
I thought, that the reason is clipAngle, and try to change it for different "maps" like that:

```
projection.clipAngle(180);
// Draw the world 
var world = 
svg.selectAll('.lands').data([land]).enter().append('path').attr("class", "lands").attr('d', path);
// Draw the cities
var cities = svg.selectAll('.cities').data([points]).enter().append('path').attr("class","cities").attr('d', path);
projection.clipAngle(90);
//Draw the countries
d3.json("https://rawgit.com/Bramsiss/Globe/master/world-counries1.json", function(collection) { 
var countries = svg.selectAll(".country").data(collection.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).attr("class", "country");
```

But it didn't work.
Next I thought to do two projections whit clipAngle (for different colors of the same maps), but it was bad idea.

Maybe it is too easy, but I try to solve this for three days, and haven't got an answer...

Also, have this in codepen (https://codepen.io/bramsis/pen/ZvzGdo)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify the `mouseover` function you are applying to your countries to work out if the country is "behind" the globe.

```
 countries
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          // we need a coordinate to work with
          // this is just a quick and dirty method - see 
          // the answer for why this part is ambiguous... 
          var data =
            d.geometry.coordinates[0][0].length == 2
              ? d.geometry.coordinates[0][0]
              : d.geometry.coordinates[0][0][0];
          // next using the coordinate we work out the angular distance 
          var ad = d3.geoDistance(data, [
            -projection.rotate()[0],
            projection.rotate()[1]
          ]);
          // if the angle is less than Pi/2
          // then the coordinate is in front of the horizon and the country 
          // is highlighted 
          if (ad < Math.PI/2) {
            this.style.stroke = "rgba(193, 0, 32, 0.5)";
          }
        })
```

obviously this is a bit rough and ready as it selects just the first coordinate that represents the country...you would need to think about what you mean by "far side" - i.e. The whole country, any part of it, 50% of it, etc? Once you define what being on the "far side" means then you can use this method to iterate over the set of coordinates that represents the portion you are interested in to see if they are in front of the horizon or not.

See a [working fork of your example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrgKXa)

To see what I mean about only using one coordinate, mouse over the antarctic for a clear demonstration - 50% of the time it is highlighted - as although some part of it is always in view the exact coordinate that the calculation is based on is only is view 50% of the time.

EDIT:

From the comment...

> Thanks, it's really work, but what if globe can rotate not only for
>   X-coordinate, but Y too.

To work with rotation around the y-axis as well as the x-axis one just needs to amend the calculation for the distance. i.e.

```
      // notice the negative phi value 
      // for reference the values are; lambda, phi, gamma
      var ad = d3.geoDistance(data, [
        -projection.rotate()[0],
        -projection.rotate()[1],
        0
      ]);
```

Obviously to see this working you need to actually rotate the globe along the y-axis too. e.g.

```
// rotate the globe over the x and y axes
// i just use slightly different values here to "tumble" the globe
projection.rotate([rotate[0] + velocity[0] * dt, velocity[0] * dt]);
```

See another [working fork with rotation in multiple directions](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVrvVm)

Also may be read upon [projection rotate](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_rotate) as it really is the key to what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Thanks, it's really work, but what if globe can rotate not only for X-coordinate, but Y too. So this can't work correctly, mb it can be solve with Math.abs()?

Comment: If you have another question you would need to ask it, and provide an example of what you are trying to do, and explain why it doesn't work. That said it should be fairly trivial and along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to overlay your contries' original paths with another layer of the same paths using `.clipAngle(90)`. Only these paths will get an event handler for the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events attached to them. That way, only front-facing countries will react to those mouse events.

The below snippet demonstrates a working solution. There is not much magic to it, as you just need to duplicate the existing logic for adding the countries. I prefixed the parts with `frontXxx` for clarity.

```
var frontProjection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .scale(radius)
  .translate(translation)
  .clipAngle(90);

var frontPath = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(frontProjection)
  .pointRadius(1);

// ...

// Inside the load() function.
var frontCountries = svg.selectAll(".frontCountry")
  .data(collection.features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", frontPath)
    .attr("class", "frontCountry")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      this.style.stroke = 'rgba(193, 0, 32, 0.5)';
    })
   .on("mouseout", function() {
      this.style.stroke = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
   });

// ...

// Rotation
var frontFeature = svg.selectAll(".frontCountry");
timer = d3.timer(function() {
  var dt = Date.now() - time;
  // ...
  frontProjection.rotate([rotate[0] + velocity[0] * dt, rotate[1] + velocity[1] * dt]);
  frontFeature.attr("d", frontPath);     
});
```

Notice, how this easily allows the rotation around multiple axes as per the request made in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47744870/far-side-of-the-globe#comment82461260_47745249) to Fraser's answer.

```js
/* Set up */
/* ====== */
var timer;
var width = 1000,
height = 700,
radius = 325,
originalScale = height / 2,
scale = originalScale,
translation = [width / 2, height / 2],
scaleChange, rotation,
rotate = [100, -1],
velocity = [.009,.005],
time = Date.now();
var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();

// set up the main canvas and the projection
var svg = d3.select('#map').append('svg').attr("id", "world").attr('width',width).attr('height',height).append('g');
var projection = d3.geoOrthographic().scale(radius).translate(translation).clipAngle(180);
var frontProjection = d3.geoOrthographic().scale(radius).translate(translation).clipAngle(90);
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection).pointRadius(1);
var frontPath = d3.geoPath().projection(frontProjection).pointRadius(1);
svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width/2).attr("cy", height/2).attr("r", radius).classed('cir', true);

/* Data load */
/* ========= */
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.csv, 'https://rawgit.com/Bramsiss/Globe/master/c.csv')
.defer(d3.json, 'https://rawgit.com/jonataswalker/map-utils/master/data/json/world-110m.json')
.await(load);

function load(error, cities, world ) {
  if (error) { console.log(error); }

  var land = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land),
      grid = graticule();

  var outerArray = [];
  cities.forEach(function(el) {

    var innerArray = [+el.Longitude, +el.Latitude];
    outerArray.push(innerArray);
  }); 

  var points = { 
    type: "MultiPoint", 
    coordinates: outerArray 
  }; 
  
  // Draw the world 
  var world = svg.selectAll('.lands').data([land]).enter().append('path').attr("class", "lands").attr('d', path);

  // Draw the cities
  var cities = svg.selectAll('.cities').data([points]).enter().append('path').attr("class","cities").attr('d', path);


  //Countries
  d3.json("https://rawgit.com/Bramsiss/Globe/master/world-counries1.json", function(collection) { 
  var countries = svg.selectAll(".country").data(collection.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).attr("class", "country");
  
    var frontCountries = svg.selectAll(".frontCountry")
      .data(collection.features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", frontPath)
        .attr("class", "frontCountry")
        .on("mouseover", function() {
          this.style.stroke = 'rgba(193, 0, 32, 0.5)';
        })
       .on("mouseout", function() {
          this.style.stroke = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
       });

 
  //Rotation
   var feature = svg.selectAll(".cities, .country, .lands");
   var frontFeature = svg.selectAll(".frontCountry");
   timer = d3.timer(function() {
   var dt = Date.now() - time;
   projection.rotate([rotate[0] + velocity[0] * dt, rotate[1] + velocity[1] * dt]);
   feature.attr("d", path);
   frontProjection.rotate([rotate[0] + velocity[0] * dt, rotate[1] + velocity[1] * dt]);
   frontFeature.attr("d", frontPath);     
      
   function rot(dt) {
     return 
   }
  });
});
}
```

```css
.country {
        fill: transparent;  
        stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }      
      .frontCountry {
        fill: darkolivegreen;  
        fill-opacity: 0.6;
        stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }      
       .lands {
        fill: transparent;  
        stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }      
      .cities {
        stroke: #2F4F4F;
        stroke-width: 12px;
        fill:  black;
        opacity:  0.8;
      }
      .cir {
    fill:none;
    stroke:black;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

<div id="map" text-align="center" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="globe"></div>
</div>
```

I have also [forked](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpvmvg) you pen to incorporate the changes.